# JSON Object response only first time

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

So I have created a simple app, that will get som data from a mysql database through PHP and json.

Here i have created a textview (text) to put some db result in, and an "update"-button, which is supposed to update from the db.
The update-button calls the UpdateFromDb method.

Apparently it does only work the first time, and I have to close and open the app to get it updating again?

```
public void UpdateFromDb() {

System.out.println("CHECK"); // <- after the first time, THIS is the only thing happening 
// when I call UpdateFromDb method..??

        reqq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        JsonObjectRequest jsonob = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                myUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray dataAr = response.getJSONArray("json_array");
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataAr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject dat = dataAr.getJSONObject(i);

                        text.setText(dataAr.getString("db_stuff"));

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println(error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        reqq.add(jsonob);
    }
```

I would really like, that you could start the app, press update-button and it updates from the db (that part works fine), and then I can put something new in the db, and when i press update-button again, it will run the whole json-part and update again.

(Guess I don't have to mention that I'm really new at this)

Can anyone help?

Comment: did you check the logs if there are any exceptions occuring ?

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be more efficient to keep the request queue outside , maybe in onCreate so its only created once ?  so move Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext()); outside of the method call.

Comment: Yeah of course - just did that.
But no - no exceptions! And I also tried putting a system.out.println inside the for loop in the json request. That only prints out the first time to.

Comment: Also tried a header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); in the PHP, and a setShouldCache(false); on the jsonObjectRequest... Still nothing.

Comment: Alright, I got it fixed... Trid a couple of strange things, like unplugging and replugging my usb cable to the phone.... It's working now, but really don't know what went down before.
Thanks anyway :)